# "expected primary expression" error - Trying to compile a smart contract on remix - ethereum ide

Tags: token, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm being honest this code is taken from a website that is supposed to ease the creation of a smart contract/token on the binance smart chain. (short backstory: Me and some friends thought it would be fun to have our own token to e.g. take bets, play poker whatsoever and are now trying to create our own through deploying our smart contract on the BSC)

Here is a link to the template I used: https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc-genesis-contract/blob/master/contracts/bep20_template/BEP20Token.template

I am trying to compile the code but in line 352 the error "expected primary expression" occurs. What does that mean? I am really just a layman. The token is supposed to be called Omega and the Symbol OHM.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked contract contains this function which causes the syntax error.

```
constructor() public {
  _name = {{TOKEN_NAME}};
  _symbol = {{TOKEN_SYMBOL}};
  _decimals = {{DECIMALS}};
  _totalSupply = {{TOTAL_SUPPLY}};
  _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

  emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}
```

I'm assuming that it was the contract author's intention to use these placeholders as a way to point out where you can fill in your own values.

After you replace the placeholders with real values, the contract compiles successfully.

```
constructor() public {
  _name = "MyToken";
  _symbol = "MyT";
  _decimals = 18;
  _totalSupply = 1000000000000000000;
  _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

  emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}
```